# Getting RTD data on top row

Tags: excel, vba

With RTD, getting new data in subsequent rows (`lrow`) as it comes in is not a problem.
But this puts new data in the last row and I want it on the top row which in my case is Row 13.
To achieve this I am  inserting a new row on Row 13 every time it gets new data from RTD formula in row 12.
But the code below is inserting 58 rows populated with each new data data as shown below the code.
`Application.Wait` of 0.5 sec has no effect and 1 sec forces updates every sec with same redundant data, blocking RTD to refresh with new data.
Each actual data inflow interval is sporadic - between one (or less?) to few secs.
What am I missing here or how can this be solved reliably pls?
TIA!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    capturerow = 12
    currow = 13

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    If Cells(12, 2) = "" Then
        Cells(currow, 1) = Format(Now(), "hh:mm:ss")
        Cells(currow, 2) = Cells(capturerow, 2)
        Cells(currow, 2).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    End If

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The output -

```
Time    Last
        RTD Formula -> Row 12
              -> Row 13
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:20 25878
1:54:18 25886
```

Comment: Try replacing of `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` followed by `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` with `Application.EnableEvents = False` followed by Application.EnableEvents = True`. When your code insets a row, the `Calculation` event is triggered again...

Comment: Still alive? Did you try my suggestion? Did it change something?

Comment: Yes, that worked, thanks much!

Comment: In our community it is at least polite to give us a sign... And maybe tick the check box on the answer code (I will post it like an answer) to make it accepted answer. In this way somebody else having a similar problem, will learn how such a problem can be solved...

Answer (score 0):

Replace, please:

`Application.ScreenUpdating = False` followed by `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`

with

`Application.EnableEvents = False` followed by `Application.EnableEvents = True`.

When your code insets a row, the `Calculation` event is triggered again..